# Orbeon form builder - limit repeating element based on field value

Tags: validation, xpath, orbeon, xforms

I am using Orbeon Form Builder and have a form with a repeat section. The no. of repeats has been set to 3 however I want to vary this depending on the value set in another field. Do you know if this is possible?

The field and repeating element are in different sections on the form.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Adding some code to the question might do good.

Comment: You mean the maximum number of repetitions?

Answer (score 0):

I created a [working example](https://gist.github.com/ebruchez/7439769). The idea:

- place an event handler reacting to a change of value of the `count` field
- depending on whether the value is larger or smaller than the current number of iterations, remove or insert new iterations
- this relies on the `xxf:bind()` function, and on knowledge of the grid repeat template

This said, as is I don't think it's a good user interface, as it can delete data upon tabbing out of the `count` field.